# Not able to build libtool 2.4.3 using gcc 4.8.2 on CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, gcc, centos6, libtool, vmware-workstation

Background:

1. Made CentOS 6.6 x64 VM on VMware workstation 10.
2. sudo yum update
3. Directly installed gcc 4.8.2 from answer given [here](https://superuser.com/a/542091).Set variables using     scl enable devtoolset-2 bash

Downloaded libtool 2.4.3

```
wget http://gnumirror.nkn.in/libtool/libtool-2.4.3.tar.gz
./configure --prefix=/usr` 
sudo make
```

[Build errors](http://pastebin.com/haQCTxhX)

[config.log](http://pastebin.com/J0PqCgtV)

$uname -a

`Linux sphirewall 2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 11 17:57:25 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

Try lower version.

It worked for me :

```
OS Centos 6.7
[root@host libtool-2.4]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

GCC version
[root@host libtool-2.4]# rpm -q gcc
gcc-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64
```

libtool from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.tar.gz